# Issue with RecyclerView item selection

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am designing a live quiz app that fetches data from server and question are displayed in a RecyclerView that contains a question and four options. Now when I select one option for a given question, it is selected properly but at the same time, the corresponding option for other question is selected automatically.

Screenshot of the item selection issue is the following.
[image: Recyclerview Item Selection Issue]
I have designed Data Model Class and RecylerView Adapter (with the help of @Reaz Murshed) but have been stuck with the code
My Data Model Class is :
//DmLiveQuiz

```
public class DmLiveQuiz {
String testId;
int questionId;
String question;
String optA;
String optB;
String optC;
String optD;
String answer;
String explain;
... 
}
```

My Adapter Class is //LiveTestAdapter

```
public class LiveTestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LiveTestAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
private List<DmLiveQuiz> questionList;
private int[] answerList; // Get a list of your answers here.
private DmLiveQuiz questionsList;
private Context context;
public List<Integer> myResponse = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public int qno;
public LiveTestAdapter(List<DmLiveQuiz> questionList, Context context) {
this.questionList = questionList;
this.context = context;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.live_quiz_display_format, parent, false);
return new CustomViewHolder(itemView);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
questionsList = questionList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
holder.tvQNo.setText(questionsList.getQuestionId() + "");
holder.tvquestion.getLayoutParams().width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
holder.tvquestion.setText(questionsList.getQuestion());
holder.optA.setText(questionsList.getOptA());
holder.optB.setText(questionsList.getOptB());
holder.optC.setText(questionsList.getOptC());
holder.optD.setText(questionsList.getOptD());
// Now you need to modify the backgrounds of your option buttons like the following.
if (answerList[position] == 1) holder.optA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
else holder.optA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
if (answerList[position] == 2) holder.optB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
else holder.optB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
if (answerList[position] == 3) holder.optC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
else holder.optC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
if (answerList[position] == 4) holder.optD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
else holder.optD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
holder.optA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
holder.optA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
answerList[position] = 1; // Selected first option which is A
});
holder.optB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
holder.optB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
answerList[position] = 2; // Selected second option which is B
Toast.makeText(context, "Position :" + holder.getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
holder.optC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
holder.optC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
answerList[position] = 3; // Selected third option which is C
 Toast.makeText(context, "Position :" + holder.getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
holder.optD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
holder.optD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
answerList[position] = 4; // Selected fourth option which is D
Toast.makeText(context, "Position :" + holder.getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
holder.tvClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
holder.optA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
holder.optB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
holder.optC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
holder.optD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_question_style);
answerList[position] = 0; // Clear the value in the answerList
}
});
}

// Use this function to set the question list in the adapter
public void setQuestionList(List<DmLiveQuiz> questionList) {
this.questionList = questionList;
this.answerList = new int[questionList.size()]; // This initializes the answer list having the same size as the question list
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return questionList.size();
}
public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
TextView tvquestion, tvClear, tvQNo;
Button optA, optB, optC, optD;
public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
super(itemView);
tvQNo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLiveQuizQuestionNo);
tvquestion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLiveQuizQuestion);
optA = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonOptionA);
...///
}
}
}
```

And The Activity where Recyclerview is implemented is

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewLiveTest);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
quizList = new ArrayList<>();
adapter = new LiveTestAdapter(quizList, getApplicationContext());
linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
// recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
getData();
        ......
```

The method for fetching JSON data is getdata() as given below which fetches data from server correctly...

```
private void getData() {
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(quiz_url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
try {
JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
DmLiveQuiz liveQuiz = new DmLiveQuiz();
...
...
quizList.add(liveQuiz);
} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
progressDialog.dismiss();
}
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
..........
}



    Now When I run App, it shows index=0 i.e. ArrayOutOfIndexException is generated.. I am not able to call public void setQuestionList(List<DmLiveQuiz> questionList) method of LiveQuizAdapter class  from my activity.. Please Help
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially you are setting empty list in the adapter. After getting value from JsonArrayRequest then need to update adapter using new list.

Update onBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
DmLiveQuiz  dmLiveQuiz= questionList.get(position);
if(dmLiveQuiz!=null){
// do whatever you want. put all code here.}

}
```

Update your adapter:

```
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
// put all code here
    quizList.add(liveQuiz);}
    adapter.setQuestionList(quizList);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, brother. You made my day. God Bless You. With your kind help, I am able to resolve the issues. Thanks, Once again.

Comment: You are genius, Sir.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a boolean value in DmLiveQuiz model class :-

```
boolean isSelected ;
```

and then set a check in your adapter while your are showing the answer is selected or not :-

```
if(DmLiveQuiz.isSelectd){
// this is the selected answer
}else {
// in case don't selected
}
```

and change the boolean value on adapter item Click

Comment: Dear Sir, I am yet to implement your solution. Thanks for your reply. I shall let you know about the progress I make after implementing your code suggestions. Thanks once again.